# parameterized Sql Query in R not working

Tags: r, sql-server-2008

I have a query in R that extracts data from SQL Server that takes column values as command line arguments. But it does not result in any output.

```
library(RODBC)
argv <- commandArgs(TRUE)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=<srvr_nm>; database=<db>; trusted_connection=true')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select  * from table where col = \'argv[1]\'')
```

This is how I am calling it

```
C:\Users\uid>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --slave --vanilla "c:\R\script.R" "abc"
```

(even if I remove the quotation from command line argument while passing that also dies not help)

The output that I get is:

```
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

When I saw what was getting passed had quotation mark... e.g. "abc"... The value stored in table is abc (without quotation). I tried to remove the quotation with

```
as.name(argv[1])
```

but it also did not help...

Then i inserted a value in table with quotation like "abc" (instead of abc)... but still it is not getting selected.

Can you help me in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `fn$` in the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)
argv <- gsub('"', '', commandArgs(TRUE)) # remove double quotes

# ...

res <- fn$sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select  * from table where col = '`argv[1]`' ")
```

or replace last line with:

```
argv1 <- argv[1]
res <- fn$sqlQuery(dbhandle, "select  * from table where col = '$argv1' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless `sqlQuery` has some special internal query parsing, the string `'argv[1]'` will not evaluate to the value of `argv[1]` but remain unparsed.

Try any of these instead

```
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle,
    paste('select  * from table where col = \'', argv[1], '\'', sep=""))
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle,
    sprintf('select  * from table where col = \'%s\'', argv[1]))
```